# Why are meromorphic functions defined on poles that are isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

I understand that meromorphic functions are functions that have poles at points which are isolated. My question is why are meromorphic functions defined like this? Do bad things happen if they weren't isolated?

Comment: Hang on, there is a fundamental problem with the current phrasing of the question. The set of singularities of meromorphic functions must have **no limit points**. This is not the same as saying that the singularities are isolated. For example, the set $A = \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb N \} $ has $0$ as a limit point in $\mathbb C$, but the elements of $A$ are nonetheless isolated. So I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Wait so are there 2 conditions: The points are isolated and the set has no limit points? My book says the set must simply have no limit points but online I've seen that they must be isolated points...

Comment: By the way, one practical benefit of insisting that the set of singularities has no limit points is that this condition ensures that the number of poles enclosed by any simple closed contour is finite. (To prove this, apply Bolzano-Weierstrass.) Therefore, the sum in the residue theorem is a finite sum.

Comment: Well, "$A$ has no limit points" implies that "the points in $A$ are isolated". In fact, saying that "the points in $A$ are isolated" is the same as saying that no element of $A$ is a limit point of $A$. But saying that "$A$ has no limit points" is stronger, because this also tells us that no point outside of $A$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: P.S. I learned my definition from Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis".

Comment: Ahhh...I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your speculation is correct: isolated singularities can be understood well, functions have Laurent expansions, etc., whether the singularity is removable, a pole, or essential. In contrast, at an accumulation point of poles (or essential singularities) we apparently have no good way to understand what a function might do.

Comment: A classical example of "bad behaviour" is given by $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}z^{n^2}$ when $|z|\to 1^{-}$.